# SQL Literal/Keywords for DateTime field in Ormlite POCO

Tags: c#, sql, postgresql, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I'm using servicestack/ormlite 4.0.32 with postgres 9.3.

I have a few `timestamp` columns in the tables (along with corresponding `DateTime` fields in their associated POCOs).

How can I use SQL literals like `NOW()`, `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` etc. in ormlite POCO `Insert()` or `Update()` methods? By default, the DateTime fields are populated with `DateTime.Min`.

I don't want to use database triggers, SQL literals such as `NOW()` are preferrable.

Answer (score 2):

The `DateTime` values that are not `Nullable<DateTime>` will default to `DateTime.Min` when you `Insert` or `Update`. Therefore you should set them to the desired value.

## Set Manually:

You can do this during your Insert or Update statement by specifying the value you want to be `DateTime.Now`

```cs
db.Insert(new Person { Id = 1, FirstName = "John", CreatedDate = DateTime.Now });
```

## Use OrmLite's Insert/Update Filters:

However I suspect that you are looking to avoid having to do this yourself in your Insert or Update statement, and this is typically handled using OrmLite's Insert/Update filter functionality, that can be used to set the record creation and modification time.

From [the documentation](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite#global-insert--update-filters):

```cs
public interface IAudit 
{
    DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }
    string ModifiedBy { get; set; }
}

OrmLiteConfig.InsertFilter = (dbCmd, row) => {
    var auditRow = row as IAudit;
    if (auditRow != null)
        auditRow.CreatedDate = auditRow.ModifiedDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
};

OrmLiteConfig.UpdateFilter = (dbCmd, row) => {
    var auditRow = row as IAudit;
    if (auditRow != null)
        auditRow.ModifiedDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
};
```

Then on your database table class:

```cs
public class MyTable : IAudit
{
    // Your properties
    ...

    // The audit properties
    DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }
    string ModifiedBy { get; set; }
}
```

When you Insert/Update `MyTable` then the filters will update the timestamps automatically.

Comment: Thanks @Scott for the detailed answer!Unfortunately, it still doesn't serve my specific requirement. The service consumers (predominantly winforms) will be spread geographically across continents - and I can't trust the technically not-so-sophisticated end-users (mostly low level medical technicians) to keep their system time in sync.

Comment: I think ormlite should implement support for SQL literals - I had scoured the documentation but failed to find any clue.. Anyways, I have implemented triggers on DB side - but I am hoping to find more elegant solution on the client end. Thanks for providing details about OrmLite audit filters!

Comment: Is there a reason why I wouldn't just set this in the constructor for my POCO's instead of having to deal with filters on insert and update?